# How to avoid loading data every time I run my program?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Currently every time I run my code (VSC) large amounts of data are being loaded, which is time-consuming. E.g.

```
with h5py.File('Galaxy10_DECals.h5', 'r') as F:
    images = np.array(F['images'])
    labels = np.array(F['ans'])
```

It takes minutes to load. I would like to load data once and then twist/rerun only a part of code I am interested in twisting/reruning.

I tried to set breakpoints, however I need something opposite to those (like startpoint after "data code"). Also, it seems that in VS Code, you can pre-select few lines of code and run those only. This is quite ugly since I need to select the rest of the program except for data load module.

Comment: Have you considered running your code in a Jupyter notebook?  Then you can load once, and test as much as you like.  You might also load just a sample of the data while developing, so it will load much more quickly.

Comment: you can use **Python Interactive** see the VSC doc pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Damian Satterthwaite-Phillips](/users/4441671) [said](/q/76134328#comment134266906_76134328), you could load in a Jupyter notebook or extract out only a small amount of the data to play with (this would also have the benefit of handling the data faster).

My go-to would be running the code in interactive mode in the terminal. Either just call `python3` (or `python`) to open an interactive session and load in lines as you wish or you can run a file and open into interactive mode once it is done with the `-i` flag: `python3 -i my_file.py` (You may need to adjust your loading so that the data will be available at the global level). From there, you can do whatever you want without having to reload the files every time.